# How do I record a script in JMeter which adds a record in a website?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Currently, I am recording a script in jmeter by which I am adding a record in a website , but a problem is that while recording a script I am able to add a record in a website, but once recording has been done and after that if I will run a script again then, a script is not adding a record in a website.

can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

In the absolute majority of cases you will not be able to replay the recorded script without performing [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start).

Modern web applications widely use dynamic parameters for [session management](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.md) or [CSRF protection](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md) so once you record your test you get "hardcoded" values and they need to be dynamic.

Assuming all above my expectation is that your test doesn't add record due to failed login or something like that. Inspect requests and responses using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener - this will allow you to identify which exact step is failing.

The process of implementing the correlation looks as follows:

1. Identify the element which looks to be dynamic either manually inspecting request parameters and look for "suspicious" patterns or record your test one more time and compare the recorded scripts looking for the parameters which differ
2. Inspect previous response and extract the dynamic value using a suitable [post-processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors). For HTML response times the best option is [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter). It will allow you to extract the dynamic parameter value and store in into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
3. Replace hardcoded recorded value with the variable from the step 2
4. Repeat for all dynamic parameters
5. Don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan.